# Why generic method that accept reference types doesn't accept nullable-types as arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, nullable, value-type

**At a glance,**

```
public static class Conversion
{
    public static T Read<T>(object value) where T :class
    {
        if (value is DBNull) return null;
        if (value is null) return null;

        if (value is Enum) return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value.ToString(), true);
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

**When** calling a `Read<T>` function

```
var myVariable = Conversion.Read<bool?>(Row[nameof(IsFetchNextRecordAfterDelete)]);
```

> Error CS0452  The type 'bool?' must be a reference type in order to use
>   it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'Conversion.Read(object)'

**Wonder why?**  the bool? is nullable that's mean its a reference type, and generic method declared `where T : class`

Comment: Nullable reference types and nullable value types are different things. A nullable value type like `bool?` is still a value type (`Nullable<bool>`, which is a `struct`). A single generic function cannot cover both nullable value types and nullable reference types. It can cover value types and non-nullable reference types, and it can cover non-nullable value types and non-nullable reference types (`where T : notnull`), but to cover both nullable value types and nullable reference types you have to 1) drop the constraint and use `default` rather than `null` or 2) provide overloads.

Comment: omg, I fully leaks C# 8.0? so does C# 8.0 fix the problem above?

Comment: No, C# 8 deliberately does not fix this because it would break backwards compatibility with existing code (even though this needs fixing in C# 8 much more badly than earlier versions). At runtime, a nullable reference type and a nullable value type are still different things, and they cannot be covered by one implementation for both. In all versions of C#, you need overloads if you want to cover both references and nullable value types; C# 8 just adds more ways to verify that references are not null.

Comment: You mean overloading the method itself. or overloading something new in C# 8.0 ? ^^

Comment: Overloading the method itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'bool?' is **not** a reference type. It is a nullable **value** type.
see [Nullable value types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)
The underlying type is a struct (which is a value type).

Answer (score 2):

`where T :class`

This constraint means that the type argument that you will provide will be a reference type that includes any class,interface, delegate, or array type.
[Type Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

Nullable-types come under the category of value types not as reference.